# Maximize the number of items bought

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

We are given an array Ai denoting the price of item i.

We have k amount of currency and we can buy the first item n times, second item n-1 times, third item n-2 times and so on. Find the maximum number of items which can be bought.

```
1<= n <= 10^4              
1<= Ai <= 10^6          
1 <= k <= 10^9
```

### What I thought

I thought its a case of 0/1 Knapsack but it will exceed the memory as the sum is very large. Is there any greedy straight forward algorithm I can't see? I don't need the code, just approach towards solving this problem will be of great help.

Comment: Why not sorting the prices, and buy the cheapest items in priority?

Comment: @Damien Because at the end, we might end up with unused currency. Fractional knapsack can't be used here

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem. You could provide an example to clarify it.

Comment: Are you required to use all of the currency? If so, you need to specify that in the question, because as the question is written, Damien's greedy approach is the correct approach.

Comment: And in fact, it's easy to come up with examples where it's not even possible to spend all of the currency. The subset sum problem doesn't always have a solution. So I don't see why you care about unused currency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to maximize the number of items you can buy you don't have a Knapsack problem (in a Knapsack problem each item has some value or weight and you want to maximize the overall weight of the items you pack). A greedy solution should work for your problem. Just sort the items according to their price (you have to remember to keep track of how many times you can buy each item, e.g. using pairs) and then buy the cheapest available until you run out of money. This should give you an O(nlog(n)) solution.

Comment: You say, "should work for your problem", suggesting you're not certain. I think you are certain, however, so I would change that to "will work for you problem". Consider providing a simple proof that the algorithm produces an optimal solution (by showing, I would suggest, that for every optimal solution there is one produced by your algorithm that is at least as good).